# Data Modeling Question for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, data-modeling

I have the following entities.

- User

  Event

  Expense

  Guest

A User is someone that is registered with my site. An event is something that a specific user can create and then invite people to (other users). An expense is created by a specific user for a specific event and can be associated with other users/guests of the event (like user A bought something for user B and user C and guest D). A guest is also created by a specific user for a specific event but once created for the event, the other users associated with that event can see the guest. A guest will never actually log into the system...it is just a placeholder for people that may have attended an event but whom are not registered on the site.

I am trying to wrap my head around the `has_many` and `belongs_to` attributes of these entities.

It is almost like in my many-to-many relationship tables I need another column which identifies the "type" of person (user or guest) so I can join properly to pull in names, etc. from the users and guests tables accordingly.

I have thought about creating a flag in the users table that says whether the record is a guest (and therefore not require that guest to register with the site, login, etc.) but that doesn't seem very clean.

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds to me like you're naturally leaning towards what is called a polymorphic association. It might be useful for you to have a look at this Railscast by Ryan Bates: [Polymorphic Associations](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Gav Polymorphic just one table people with a column type and tada

```
class Person < ActiveRecord:Base
   #methods and associations all people have
end
class User < Person
   #methods and associations specific to users
end
class Guest < Person
   #methods and associations specific to guests
end
```

Comment: if i went with this approach then its looks like there is one physical database table called people that holds both users and guests which a flag to indicate which one. my users are being created via restful_authentication plugin so i dont know how well that will work. do you see any issues with that. if this works then the need for polymorphic association goes away right (since the items that would make the association polymorphic are now contained in the same physical table)?

Comment: as long as the people table has all of the fields required for users/restful auth it shouldn't be a problem.